# Photoshop: Setting default background colour of each new layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Is there a way to set the default background colour of each new layer to white? Currently each layer I create has a transparent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Action that will make a new layer and fill it with white, assign it to a hotkey and use it instead of default New Layer command.

Answer (score 0):

New **Layers** are always transparent. there's no method to have all new layers be white. You simply need to fill the new layer if you want it to be a color. With default ... you could .... New Layer then Command/Ctrl + Delete to fill with the background color (white by default)

You *could* use `Layer > New Fill Layer > Solid Color` to add new layers, but this may not be what you are seeking either. It creates a color layer with a mask, not a simple layer with a color fill.